# Selenium IDE - checking for a 404 error

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide, invalid-url

Im trying to check if a url entered into the target field for the command "checkUrl" is valid or not using javascript, but i keep getting an error. There are multiple pages listed within the sites I'm testing and I have the need to verify if the pages have been added with the correct name, or even at all using the relative url.

```
Selenium.prototype.doCheckUrl = function(locator){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  

request.open('GET', locator, true);  
request.send();  

if (request.status === "404") {  
request.message = false ;

} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to exists a simple answer.
You can take a look at the following answers:

- [How do I ask Selenium IDE to check a HTTP Status Code (e.g. 2XX, 404, 500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391511/how-do-i-ask-selenium-ide-to-check-a-http-status-code-e-g-2xx-404-500)
- [Selenium IDE - always fail on any 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228700/selenium-ide-always-fail-on-any-500-error)
- [Checking HTTP Status Code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354827/checking-http-status-code-in-selenium)

Ektor

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the full discussion here : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141

But, it seems that the dev team is opposed to this feature :(